Table having 150000+ rows responding too slow
I am facing strange Slowness some times it says #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction & in my specific MySQL table.
I have below table which have id and TBO_code as index as shown below in the structure along with more than 150000 rows data
--
-- Table structure for table `TBO_hotels`
--

CREATE TABLE `TBO_hotels` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TBO_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `Map` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HotelFacilities` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `featured_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `images` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `Attractions` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckInTime` text NOT NULL,
  `CheckOutTime` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `TBO_hotels`
--
ALTER TABLE `TBO_hotels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `TBO_code` (`TBO_code`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `TBO_hotels`
--
ALTER TABLE `TBO_hotels`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

When I otry to search Rows with respect to column city_code * (column value use in other city codes main table)*, it gives respond very slow
even if I just simply browse table or try to sort with phpMyAdmin,
Below is an example query, I searched the global variable and found nothing strange in global settings aswell.
Even I already have the correct index data but response is slow in that particular table.

SELECT *,
(SELECT count(TBO_code) from TBO_hotelswhere city_code =115936
) as TotalCount
FROM TBO_hotels
where city_code = 115936
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 0,50;

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, as all seems correct.

Add EXPLAIN before your query for full details, but chances are you need an index on city_code.

@ceejayoz i had actually index earlier city_code but i removed it as it is not unique, but yes it is foreign key of other cities table. So do you believe i should use it as index?

@TechChef Yes, foreign keys should be indexed for performance and foreign keys should be declared for referential integrity. While we're giving general advice, use datetime for timestamps; don't store images in the database, definitely not as text, store the image on disk and only store a path to the image.

@Schwern yes in images only storing a path like https://example.com/my-img.png, https://example.com/my-img2.png

@Schwern can datetime make signinficant role?

@TechChef Switching to datetime will not affect this query, it's just a good idea. They definitely should not be text. Use text in MySQL with caution.

please don't show a create table plus alter tables: edit your question to show output of show create table TBO_hotels;.  and show output of explain select...rest of your query

Something is holding a lock
At first glance, the problem is because there is no index on city_code. While yes, that is a problem, it shouldn't be performing that badly. 150,000 rows is not large. The query completes in less than 100ms on my laptop.
The problem is right in the error message: #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded. Something is locking the table, or a row in the table, for a long time.
With and without an index
Without an index on city_code, it must search the whole table. First it must scan the whole table find all matching rows and count them (Table scan on test below). Then it will scan the id index (Index scan on test using PRIMARY) until it finds 50 rows with a matching city_code (Filter: (test.city_code = 115936)). Depending on how city codes are distributed, this is potentially the whole table. In my test data, with 450,000 rows it had to search 150050 rows ((actual time=0.0488..51.4 rows=150050 loops=1))
mysql> explain analyze SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) from test where city_code =115936 ) as TotalCount FROM test where city_code = 115936 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,50;                                      
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| -> Limit: 50 row(s)  (cost=4.53 rows=5) (actual time=51.9..66.1 rows=50 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (test.city_code = 115936)  (cost=4.53 rows=5) (actual time=51.9..66.1 rows=50 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on test using PRIMARY  (cost=4.53 rows=50) (actual time=0.0488..51.4 rows=150050 loops=1)
-> Select #2 (subquery in projection; run only once)
    -> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=49878 rows=1) (actual time=152..152 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (test.city_code = 115936)  (cost=45369 rows=45088) (actual time=39..152 rows=1504 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on test  (cost=45369 rows=450883) (actual time=0.0597..111 rows=451504 loops=1)
 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

If we add an index, MySQL doesn't necessarily use the index well. Here is the plan after adding an index on city_code and optimize table test. It does effectively the same thing, but it now scans the whole city_code index.
mysql> explain analyze SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) from test where city_code =115936 ) as TotalCount FROM test where city_code = 115936 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,50;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| -> Limit: 50 row(s)  (cost=4.65 rows=5) (actual time=58.1..71.7 rows=50 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (test.city_code = 115936)  (cost=4.65 rows=5) (actual time=58.1..71.7 rows=50 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on test using PRIMARY  (cost=4.65 rows=50) (actual time=0.0393..57.1 rows=150050 loops=1)
-> Select #2 (subquery in projection; run only once)
    -> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=51052 rows=1) (actual time=149..149 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (test.city_code = 115936)  (cost=46530 rows=45216) (actual time=17.3..148 rows=1504 loops=1)
            -> Covering index scan on test using test_city_code_idx  (cost=46530 rows=452155) (actual time=0.0345..106 rows=451504 loops=1)
 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 4 warnings (0.22 sec)

Find the lock
Perhaps there is a query locking the table, such as a large insert or update. Because this query must scan the whole table, an exclusive lock on any row potentially blocks the whole query. Check your slow query log and check for locks.

Thank you for your brief response
i had actually index earlier city_code but i removed it as it is not unique, but yes it is foreign key of other cities table. So do you believe i should use it as index?
Could you please highlight what you think i should consider to check?


Either you have a very, very slow disk, or there is some other issue.



@TechChef I answered about the foreign keys in the question comments. Like I said in the answer, a large insert or update or delete could be locking the table blocking your query. Check your slow query log, and check for locks.

but i am not inserting anything in the table currently i am only using it for select can lock table impact on select query and can it be unlocked? as it is even slow on browse

@TechChef selects should only get a shared lock, meaning many selects can read at the same time. Something is holding a lock, I can't tell you what. You'll have to check.

ok let me check what it can be, do you have any clue from where i have to start checking?

I noticed it says Next autoindex 1,352,979 can it effect?

i got below warning, do you have any idea what can cause this
Warning: #1739 Cannot use ref access on index 'TBO_code' due to type or collation conversion on field 'TBO_code'

i have created new table and make first column unique then inserting data, now it seems warning removed. I am waiting to done import of all 150000 rows then will comes to final conclusion

@TechChef That warning is not likely to have any effect on performance, nor is recreating the table going to solve it. See this answer for an explanation (you probably wrote where tdo_code = 1234 but tbo_code is not a number, it is a string, so MySQL will not use the index). Changing things you don't understand is only going to cause more problems. I'd recommend you look up what these errors mean before taking any action.

Try following query to see LOCK tables and then UNLOCK it
SHOW OPEN TABLES 
WHERE `Table` LIKE '%wp_%' 
  AND `Database` LIKE '[DB NAME]' 
  AND In_use > 0;


it is not in Lock table
